# Use Ruby On Rails on Chromebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, chromebook

I am leaning Ruby on Rails but, I have a chromebook. Is there a way to install it on a chromebook or use it? The chromebook is latest version.

Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cloud ide from a browser like c9.io

Comment: Thank You that is very helpful!